# Is there a way to get a modal display when ⌘-⌥-→ and ⌘-⌥-←?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, ui

When switching between applications with the keyboard (i.e. ⌘-tab) a modal display is shown with graphical representations of each application.

Is there a way to get a similar modal display when switching between tabs of an application (i.e. ⌘-⌥-→ and ⌘-⌥-←), such that some summary is displayed (e.g. in a browser the tab text, in sublime the filename, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Witch**](https://manytricks.com/witch/) can do this, but its development has been a bit stale (I don't know if it still works).

> **Window switching is fast and fun**
>
> With Witch installed, a pop-up panel shows all open windows—even windows in other Spaces, if you're running 10.6. From the panel, simply select the window you'd like to activate. There is no step two!
>
> [image]

Comment: It's cool that it is supported all the way back to 10.6.  It would be cooler if it were open source.  But it is definitely in line with what I'm looking for.  Thank you!